# About the Firestore query-data documentation specifically DocumentSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the [Firestore query-data get-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) docs I want to know in what situation the `document != null` will evaluate to false? Shouldn't it instead be `!document.exists()`

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you're right - the `DocumentSnapshot` should not be `null` but it might not exist, so [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#exists()) should be used here. The [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) reference documentation doesn't mention that [`getResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) could return `null` either.

Comment: And in fact, the other examples (importantly the Java one too) all use `exists()`, except Android and Objective-C.

Comment: Just started migrating to Cloud Firestore and it helps if the docs are correct but I see now CF is in Beta so no wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onComplete()` callback provides a Google [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) instance of `Task<DocumentSnapshot>` and calling [`getResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getResult()) on this should return a `DocumentSnapshot`, and never `null`.

This piqued my interest though so I did a little testing: I  attached an `OnCompleteListener` to a document that I know doesn't exist:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("this-does-not-exist")
        .document("neither-does-this")
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (task.getResult() == null) Log.d(TAG, "getResult is null");
                    Log.d(TAG, "getResult: " + task.getResult());
                }
            }
});
```

When executed, the `task.getResult() == null` check evaluates to `false` and therefore the message "getResult is null" is **not** written to the log.

However, calling `toString()` on the return from `getResult()` throws the below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This document doesn't exist. Use DocumentSnapshot.exists() to check whether the document exists before accessing its fields.
```

This explicitly states to use [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#exists()) rather than a null-check, but the [documentation for "get a document"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) says:

> Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by **docRef**, the resulting **document** will be null.

Furthermore, examples in other languages on the same documentation page all use `exists()`, except Android and Objective-C. Most importantly: the Java example uses `exists()`:

> ```
> DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
> // asynchronously retrieve the document
> ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
> // ...
> // future.get() blocks on response
> DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
> if (document.exists()) {
>   System.out.println("Document data: " + document.getData());
> } else {
>   System.out.println("No such document!");
> }
> ```

In this case, I'd wager that this seems to be an error in the documentation, and we should be using `document.exists()` rather than `document != null`.

Comment: [You can submit feedback for the documentation page using the `Send Feedback` button, top-right of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkWow.jpg)

Comment: Thank you, I've been wondering why they are doing the null check because it seems not necessary.