# Firestore - Why check if DocumentSnapshot is not null AND call exists?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Take a look at this code example from the `Firestore` documentation:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Why check if `document != null`? If I read the source code correctly (beginner), the `exists` method checks for nullity internally.

Comment: Which `ifExists` method are you referring to? But the point is, if `document` is null, you cannot call any methods of it or you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, don't downvote.

Comment: check for null is not necessary here exists will is already doing a job of null.

Comment: @NoumanCh No, `exists` is not even called if `document` is `null` (an NPE is thrown before that).

Comment: I tried it with a document reference to a non existing document and NO NPE is thrown.

Comment: The answer in this thread implies that my concerns are correct, the null check is not necessary:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350129/about-the-firestore-query-data-documentation-specifically-documentsnapshot

Comment: It may be that the null check is not necessary but the reason is certainly not that `exists` does any checks.

Comment: Yes, I got that part wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I fixed the snippet here: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/commit/58973e33dfdd39a9ded36e7e6887c8feef7493b1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A successfully completed task will never pass `null` for the `DocumentSnapshot`. If the requested document does not exist, you'll get an empty snapshot. This means that:

- Calling `document.exists()` returns false
- Calling `document.getData()` throws an exception

So there is indeed no reason to check if `document != null` before calling `document.exists()`.

Comment: Thank you. Good to see that my conclusions were right, because I am a beginner.

Comment: And what about the `onEvent` method in the `EventListener`? If I check for an exception and no exception was thrown, is the `DocumentSnapshot` there always NOT null as well?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: *Googler here*. I wrote the code snippet in question and you're right, the `null` check is not needed.  I guess I was just feeling extra careful that day.  I will fix it!

Answer (score 3):

If you execute the following statement:

```
document != null
```

It will be evaluated to `false`, which means that your `task` is `null` and the following message will be printed out:

```
Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
```

However, if you are calling a method on your `task` object, (e.g. toString()) it will throw the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This document doesn't exist. Use DocumentSnapshot.exists() to check whether the document exists before accessing its fields.
```

This message explicitly tells you to use [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists()) method rather than to check for nullity.

The official documentation regarding the use of [how to get a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)  method says:

> Note: If there is no document at the location referenced by **docRef**, the resulting **document** will be null.

Comment: I actually think that documentation may be wrong. As far as I know the `DocumentSnapshot` will never be `null`. See https://jsbin.com/wesareq/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks Alex! In the meantime we updated the documentation to be more explicit about the return value.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Nice to hear that. I'll take a look right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if `documentSnapshot` is `nullable` you should do the following:

```
if (documentSnapshot != null) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
         //exists
    } else {
         //doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but you dont need multiple if statements. Remove the first statement and replace with this line
```
assert documentSnapshot != null;
```

Comment: @esmail What if we want to check if the certain field of the requested document exists or not? I get a bad state exception If I try to get the field of the document if it doesn't exist. Below is the question, kindly give it a minute
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937605/bad-state-cannot-get-a-field-on-a-documentsnapshotplatform-which-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward fix for such errors would be

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

 assert documentSnapshot != null;
 if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

      //Your operation e.g
     ArrayList<String> obj= (ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("documentObject");
     String s = Objects.requireNonNull(obj).toString();
     Toast.makeText(context, "THIS WORKS "+ s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  } else {
     //Another operation
   Toast.makeText(context, "DOES NOT EXIST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```