# Cloud Firestore: Query to check if a username exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem regarding my `userNameExistsAlready`-method in my Android App.
Basically, I have a Cloud Firestore database with the collection `user`.
Its documents are only populated with `username`, `password` and `email` (all String). Document IDs are auto-generated. I've created an `RegisterActivity` which works fine. Here is the `onCreate(..)` method of my RegisterActivity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

userNameInput = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameInput);
emailInput = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInput);
passwordInput = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
Button registerButton = findViewById(R.id.createAccountButton);

registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        userNameText = userNameInput.getText().toString();
        emailText = emailInput.getText().toString();
        passwordText = passwordInput.getText().toString();
        if (validateInputs()) {
            saveUser();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Inputs invalid! Please correct.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void saveUser() {
        if (new UserDatabaseModel(userNameText, passwordText, emailText).saveUser()) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Creation Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here is my UserDatabaseModel.java file:

```
public class UserDatabaseModel {
    public final static String DATABASE_DECLARATION = "user";
    private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public UserDatabaseModel(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public UserDatabaseModel() {

    }

    public boolean saveUser() {

        try {
            db.collection(UserDatabaseModel.DATABASE_DECLARATION).document().set(this);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

My `validateInputs()`-method does some basic stuff such as checking the length of the inputs, as well as it calls `if (userNameExistsAlready()) { return false}`.
Now the important part, the `userNameExistsAlready()`-method:

```
    private boolean userNameExistsAlready() {
        Query mQuery = db.collection(UserDatabaseModel.DATABASE_DECLARATION)
                .whereEqualTo("username", userNameText);

        mQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot ds: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                    if (ds!=null && ds.exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username Exists Already!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
}
```

This code always finds at least one DocumentSnapshot with the given username, the one I just typed in(of course without having it actually saved, because the save-method only gets called if `validateInputs() == true`[this is the thing that confuses me]), and more if there are more saved already. Do I miss something here (I thought at least the `ds.exists()`-call would make sure these files are IN the DB already) or what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to use `addSnapshotListener`. This is used only when you want to get realtime updates from the database but it's not your case. You only want to check a username for existens and for that, only a `get()` call is required.

```
mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */)
```

Second, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705216/firestore-why-check-if-documentsnapshot-is-not-null-and-call-exists/49705602), `ds!=null && ds.exists()` is not required. You only need to check if `ds.exists()`.

And the last thing you need to know is that you can **not** rely on what value your `userNameExistsAlready()` method returns. In most cases it will be false and this is because the `onEvent()` method in your case or `onComplete()` / `onSuccess()` in case of using a `get()` call, are `asynchronous`. This means that by the time your method returns the result, you haven't finished loading the data from the database. So a quick solve for this would be to use all your logic inside the `onEvent()` method or if you want to use it outside, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679)** and also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)**.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've now only added a onCompleteListener in which I basically call `task.getResult().getDocuments();` and afterwords go through that list to filter out all nonexisting ones: `for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : snapshots) { if (!snapshot.exists()) { snapshots.remove(snapshot)}}` and  afterwords check the size of the list and yes: It really works now :D Now I just need to figure out an elegant way to check all relevant fields beforehand, and not just the `username`.

Thanks for the help, especially with the insight you provided(the queries being asynchronous etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this

```
public void checkFieldIsExist(String key, String value, OnSuccessListener<Boolean> onSuccessListener) {
    db.collection("users").whereEqualTo(key, value).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        private boolean isRunOneTime = false;

        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (!isRunOneTime) {
                isRunOneTime = true;
                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                if (e != null) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    String message = e.getMessage();
                    onSuccessListener.onSuccess(false);
                    return;
                }

                if (snapshotList.size() > 0) {
                    //Field is Exist
                    onSuccessListener.onSuccess(false);
                } else {
                    onSuccessListener.onSuccess(true);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
 checkFieldIsExist("username", "dummy", new OnSuccessListener<Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {
                                if(aBoolean){
                                    //
                                }else{
                                    //username is exist
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

You can use it instead of OnSuccesListener

```
public interface OnCompleteListener<T> {
    void onComplete(T result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I modified this code a bit and it reads way better than my code before that(added `String collection` to the `checkFieldIsExist`-method and had to declare the onSuccessListener as final in the method), but it still does not seem to work. Even if the Database is fully cleared, `snapshotList.size()` always reports AT LEAST 1. Any other idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Can you debug for see what item came from the list.

Comment: Sure. All done on a (again) fresh DB.    
I/System.out: 1
    {password=test, email=test@test.com, username=testuser}  
  
This is exactly what I entered. I don't understand how this can be queried if I didn't even call the save function yet. edit: this was a `System.out.println(snapshot.getData())`

Comment: ctrl+shift+f and search test@test.com in project

Comment: There indeed was one entry, but this happens with literally any email, username (i even checked for username only atm) or/and password.  It also does not appear to be a caching issue in that sense, because I tested this many times with completely different/weird etc. usernames.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the problem. `private boolean isRunOneTime = false;

        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (!isRunOneTime) {`  Do you use the variable isRunOneTime. Beacuse, the listener is re-triggered when the record is added to the database when it is not used

Comment: Yes, I use it because I just copied most of your code.
My problem is that chedkFieldIsExist always finds something, even though I (think) I haven't called the save() method yet. Say in my activity, I enter ANYthing that is valid (valid email, etc.), it will always say that it found an entry with this Username (but how? I haven't saved it yet I think) and thus won't save.