# Why does Android Studio indicate that an object might be null when it cannot be?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, lint

This is the code that I'm using:

```
ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
        }
    }
});
```

And this how Android Studio highlights the error:

[image]

As I understand from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708909/5246885):

> A successfully completed task will never pass `null` for the `DocumentSnapshot`.

How can I solve this without checking for nullity? Thanks!

Comment: `A successfully completed task` returns never but task not completed successfully then what will become??  what can you expect??

Comment: @TanveerMunir I'm not sure I understand what you say. The task is returned successfully since I use `if (task.isSuccessful())`, right?

Comment: if `task.getResult()`  might be returns null due to not have results but tasks completed then the `document` might be null so how can you Initialize?

Comment: @TanveerMunir `if (task.isSuccessful())` it means that `task.getResult()` can never return `null`? It can only return an empty snapshot but **not** `null. Am I wrong?

Comment: The detection is limited. While it's never null if it's successful, the compiler doesn't know that. It sees a nullable return you don't check

Comment: @TanveerMunir There is no place in the docs that says that it can return `null`.

Comment: @Zoe You say it cannot return `null` even if Android Studio complains about that? So it's an Android Studio issue and not a coding problem, right?

Comment: @JohansBormman assuming what you said about the bool check is true and correct, yes.

Comment: @Andy lint checking is some times a part of the compiler

Comment: As @Zoe said, it's limited. In your case, it can't be `null`. However, `DocumentSnapshot` can be a `null` object normally . And you are calling a method of an object that has the possibility of being `null` so you get the warning. To remove the warning, you can just change that `if` statement to something like `if(document != null && document.exists())`

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ I understand now, but as long as it cannot be null, I don't want to make another check without any reason but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does Android Studio indicate that an object might be null when it
>   cannot be?

Because lint cannot know. `document.exists()` can return null in general and that's why you see the warning. Lint performs basic checks and doesn't know the details about the Firebase API. You can even reproduce this behaviour with the Java Core API.

> How can I solve this without checking for nullity? Thanks!

If you are 100% sure that it can never be null, you can use

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")

But I would not recommend that, because you don't know if the Firebase API will change in the future. Maybe the next version of Firebase will allow null returns.

Comment: @JohansBormman An alternative solution would be to use `Objects.requireNotNull` for the desired call. `@SuppressWarnings` is too big.